# Looking for a very simple board

Tags: input, board

I’ve worked with esp8266/esp32 boards in the past and they were great. But now I have a very simple project where both of these are way too powerful.

I want to read one analog input over USB per COM. That’s it. No wifi, no Bluetooth, no 32 bit or any of these *fancy things*.
It should be programmable without any hardware other than a computer though. It doesn’t need to be Arduino. All it has to do is to read the input and respond to serial communication.

But I’m absolutely overwhelmed by all these microcontrollers. Most of them are feature packed.

So I’m asking for a way to find a proper controller/board on my own. Feel free to recommend one though.

Comment: How about the Arduino Nano?

Comment: There is a non-exhaustive list of Arduino and similar boards on Wikipedia which may be of use in the comparison. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Also there is a great article “When Less Is More - The Smallest Arduino Boards for Your Needs in 2022” by Matteo Parenti on all3dp.com with a well written comparison of small form factor arduinos and clones. https://all3dp.com/2/smallest-arduino-board/

Answer (score 1):

Since you require USB, nano/micro are your way forward.
being mass produced anything smaller would actually turnout to be more expensive.

If you for those reading this message latter: If you do not need USB then you have a pro-miny (needs USB->ttl for programing)

If you are going really minimalist you can go with MSP430 chips (arduino programming available via PlatformIO).
Atmega32u4 can although run on its own without crystal, but I find Crystal free (using builtin crystal) run of MSP430 much better with timing.
Problem with MSP430 is that TI software development dedepartment is stuck in middle ages. (I am not sure if they even employ a full-time programmer) and if you are programming on arm, you might Have a problem compiling it from arm platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have some experience, seemingly these are valid options:

1. Obtain the smallest Arduino you can get. For example, a DigiSpark  original or clone, or a DFRobot Beetle. Use the Arduino IDE to program it.
2. Obtain the smallest AVR board you can get. For example, with an ATmega32u4. Download ASF, the Atmel Software Framework, learn how to use it. It provides a lot of sources for ADC and USB.

Comment: Keep in mind that sometimes "less is less".  The entire Arduino ecology is pretty cheap, so  maybe concentrate on ease-of-use instead of hardware features.  After all, if you value your time at some non-zero dollar amount, it may be that using a more 'feature-rich' (but still cheap) Arduino-ish board will be cheaper (and less frustrating) in the end.